# Jsoup Form Posting to ASPX/ Same Page Issues

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to log into a website with Jsoup. When you log in manually, there's a form for your username and a form for your password, and you click on a button that transports you to a different page.

It's not working with Jsoup, though. I suspect that the problem is that the URL of the page is the same one that is given in the form's action attribute. It's also not a PHP page, but rather an ASPX one. Can anyone offer any help? My code is below:

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... loginInfo) {
        try {
            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://websiteHere.org/directory/Login_Student_PXP.aspx")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            currentPage = Jsoup.connect("https://websiteHere.org/directory/Login_Student_PXP.aspx")
                    .data("username", "usernameGoesHere")
                    .data("password", "passwordGoesHere")
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to log in.");
        }
        return currentPage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
        loadPageFinished();
    }
}
```

Additional information: I replaced the name of the website with websiteHere.org/directory, but the Login_Student_PXP.aspx is still accurate.

The form is as follows: `<form name="Form1" method="post" action="Login_Student_PXP.aspx" id="Form1">`

It doesn't have the websiteHere.org/directory in front of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The page also has two hidden inputs, `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="6A78CD7E">` and `<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAATriMevoEM8VekHWnEl5C3PKhoCyVdJtLIis5AgYZ/RYe4sciJO3Hoc68xTFtZGQEgSYOQVAPr9tiF9q7nSHjzouKtiufdoMJr/iFLaXnXfphkEj5veiwEQz7j1yxouXII=">`. I tried adding them to my code as separate .data commands, but they don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I forgot to add a .data command for a hidden input.